# What is the default value for StackPanel.Orientation?

Tags: wpf, stackpanel

Is it Horizontal or Vertical? The [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.stackpanel.orientation?view=net-5.0) doesn't say it in the description.
I keep forgetting it and I thought someone must have asked that before but I couldn't find it.

Answer (score -2):

> Orientation has a default value of "Vertical"

It is mentioned in [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.stackpanel.orientation?view=net-5.0) but hidden in a comment of the example.